# How to compute yaw of the vector location from another vector?

Tags: c++, 3d, angle

How would I compute the yaw of an object in 3D space?
I know the coordinates of my current position ( start vector ) and my target ( end vector ).

For example, I'm facing north so my current yaw is 0 degrees or 360.
The object is located on my left and its yaw -30 degrees then how to calculate this yaw when I'm facing other side for example

[image]

in unreal engine there's such thing as https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Rotator/FindLookatRotation/
I'm wondering how this function can be implemented without dependency on unreal engine' lib

Comment: Sound more like you have a math problem than a programming problem at this point.

Comment: Project the two vectors on the ground plane by discarding the `y` value. Use atan2() to find the corresponding yaw of each vector. Subtract the two yaw values.

Comment: previous comment was if you had two directions. If you have two positions, subtract them, use atan2 to get the yaw from source position, subtract the current yaw to get the difference

Comment: @Jeffrey The output is wrong. Am I doing something wrong?                                                    `CVector vec = __g.vecNavigationMarkerPosition - *__g.vecPlayerPosition;
        float angle1 = atan2(vec.fX, vec.fZ);
        float angle2 = atan2(__g.vecPlayerPosition->fX, __g.vecPlayerPosition->fZ);
        std::cout << (angle1 - angle2) * 180.f / M_PI << std::endl;`

Comment: with the `angle1` above, you need `angle2` to be the current heading yaw.

Comment: @Jeffrey buy I don't want it to be dependent on my camera pos, in unreal engine I've done it without camera vector

Comment: @CakeCode you seem to want the number of degree your airplane needs to turn left or right, to face somewhere. Certainly, in order to do that, you need to know the current direction your airplane is facing. This has nothing to do with camera, it has to do with the current airplane heading.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, however, computing an angle out of 360 degrees is tricky when you work with vectors that give you the negative representation of an angle's direction.

A simple fix for this could reside in the usage of an inverse function which applies the operand of your current returned angle, and then alternates it out with a inverted operand.

Anything over 180 usually becomes negative, so try to focus on remembering angle inverses opposed to the entire 360 degree rotation.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68JN9.png)